# Manage restart container from sidecar in the same pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod with two containers :

1. A component with input file and does not support hot reload, to handle my new set of files i need to restart it with the new files in a particulary directory.
2. A sidecar who handle "event" and communicate with the other container

What i want to do is from my sidecar container pull specific file, and relaunch the other container, with the new set of files.

Is it possible, or a better solution exist ?

Thanks

Comment: A.  This is voodoo.  B.  You can hack it and purposely crash the container/pod.  C.  This is voodoo.  D.  You configuration data should exist outside of the container IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

[git-sync](https://github.com/kubernetes/git-sync) is a simple command that pulls a git repository into a local directory. It is a perfect "sidecar" container in Kubernetes - it can periodically pull files down from a repository so that an application can consume them.